# Can i send a object to a reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I would like to ask if it is possible to send a whole object to the reactive form in angular 2.

This is my form:

```
this.parameterForm = this.fb.group({

  'name': ['', Validators.required],
  'description': "",
  'parameterType':''
});
```

The third attribute (parameterType) should be a object. (The name and description are only plain strings.

My HTML for the parameterType is(formControlName is used to map it):

```
<label for="parameterType">Parameter Type</label>
<select id="parameterType" class="form-control" formControlName="parameterType">
  <option *ngFor="let parameterType of parameterTypes" [value]="parameterType">
    {{parameterType.name}}
  </option>

</select>
```

The values in the select are objects (which are created elsewhere). When submitting the form, I would like to have the parameterType object. The submit is trying to parse the form to a object called Parameter:

```
export class Parameter {

  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public description: string;

  public parameterType? : ParameterType
}
```

But when im trying to read the result in the console, the parameterType contains just a string "[Object object]", which looks like the parameterType is just a String and when submitting the form, the object is converted to a simple string.

My submit function is like this:

```
  onSubmit( {parameter}:{parameter: Parameter} ) {
    console.log(parameter);
  }
```

Now im just doing it so, that into parameterType im sending the id and through a service I get the object but this solution is not very nice. Do you know any way i could pass the object to the form?

Thanks

Comment: Try console the parameter as console.log(JSON.stringify(parameter)); to make sure the parameter is an object or not

Comment: stringify returns me this: {"name":"entered name","description":"entered description","parameterType":"[object Object]"} so i think it is just a string now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need to use [ngValue] instead of [value].

Answer (score 4):

You have several options :

Let's say I have the following form :

```
user: FormGroup;

this.user = this.formBuilder.group({
  account: this.formBuilder.group({
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(EmailRegex)]],
    password: ['', Validators.required],
    passwordConfirm: ['', Validators.required]
  }, { validator: this.matchingPasswords('password', 'passwordConfirm') })
});
```

From there, you can set values of your form with an `Object` :

```
let user: SignUp = {
  account: {
    email: this.mail,
    password: '',
    passwordConfirm: ''
  }
};
this.user.setValue(user);
```

Where `Signup` is an interface :

```
export interface SignUp {
  account: {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    passwordConfirm: string;
  }
}
```

You can this way create a new `Object` from your form :

```
let jsonResult = {
  email: this.user.value.account.email,
  password: this.user.value.account.password
};
```

or use the form as an Object from an interface (with `@Output` for example) :

```
@Output() randomOutput= new EventEmitter<SignUp>();

let data: SignUp = Object.assign({}, this.user.value);

this.randomOutput.emit(data);
```